# How to create automated animation for a button in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Could anyone help me create an animated button in Android studio, which wouldn't require anything to execute the animation (clicking etc.)? I am ok with any cool animation, but as I said, I would like to have the animation automated. I have already tried to search for hours looking for answers but everyone knows just how to make the animation come after clicking the button. I am using Java.

Comment: what do you mean by automated?

Comment: The animation would start instantly when I open the app and continue infinite times.